# bmatrix of sub-arrays goes out margins

Tags: amsmath, margins, matrices

I have the following reproducible code snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{Replace the sequence of tokens per trainable column by the relative array of embeddings, using as map the output of the previous step}\newline
For example the column actors, which has the following structure\newline
['tom hanks', 'tim allen', 'don rickles', 'jim varney', 'wallace shawn', 'john ratzenberger', 'annie potts', 'john morris', 'erik von detten', 'laurie metcalf', 'r. lee ermey', 'sarah freeman', 'penn jillette', 'jack angel', 'spencer aste']
\begin{center}
    $\,\Big\downarrow\,$
\end{center}
\begin{bmatrix} 
[-0.30834767, &-0.26681098, &-0.2173222,  &-0.11151562, &-0.27951762, \ldots x_i = 300],\\
[-0.1721798, &-0.25406063, &-0.38693774, &-0.19798501, &-0.257399, &-0.05970115 \ldots, x_i = 300],\\
[-0.2399106, &-0.21202469, &-0.28024384, &-0.2577843, &-0.257399,\ldots x_i = 300] \\ \ldots (m=15)
\end{bmatrix}
\ \\

\end{document}
```

And the output is this,
[image]

As you can guess I would like to erase any additional space and also keep it inside margins. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You also want to remove the large vertical spacings?

Comment: Since your matrix is extremely wide it will most likely not fit into the margins of a standard `article` whicl still keeping the number redable. Do you really need that many decimal places? If not, reducing them might already be sufficient. You could also decrease margins/ increase the textwidth.

Comment: Please keep in mind that your current MWE is not compilable since `bmatrix` can not be used outside of math mode. Your screenshow also reveals that your thesis actually does not compile either but results in abunch of error messages. (See the small red box next to the "recompile" button.) Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. ...

Comment: ... Instead of trying to fix an "output" that is not really an output, take a look at the error messages and try to fix them. Once your document compiles without errors take a look at the resulting pdf file and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot for your suggestions. I understand what you write, and I admit that I have many debugging to do, since this is a template and I just copy-paste my writing on it. So it's not a template that I initiated. Also, the fact that I take code snippets from online Latex forums when I experience an error is also something that would definitely cause an error. Just to let you know that most of my errors are due to uncompiled packages. I apologize If my questions are not totally clear. I am trying to post my best shot. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{Replace the sequence of tokens per trainable 
column by the relative array of embeddings, using as 
map the output of the previous step}

% enable rounding to 4 digits after decimal marker:
\sisetup{table-format=-1.4,  
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=4}
         
For example the column actors, which has the 
following structure

['tom hanks', 'tim allen', 'don rickles', 
 'jim varney', 'wallace shawn', 'john ratzenberger', 
 'annie potts', 'john morris', 'erik von detten', 
 'laurie metcalf', 'r. lee ermey', 'sarah freeman', 
 'penn jillette', 'jack angel', 'spencer aste']
\begin{gather*}
\Big\downarrow \\
\begin{bmatrix*}[l]
[\begin{array}{@{} *{5}{S} l @{}}
-0.30834767 &-0.26681098 &-0.2173222  &-0.11151562 &-0.27951762 &\ldots\ x_i = 300
\end{array}] \\
[\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{S} l @{}}
-0.1721798  &-0.25406063 &-0.38693774 &-0.19798501 &-0.257399 &-0.05970115 &\ldots\ x_i = 300
\end{array}] \\
[\begin{array}{@{} *{5}{S} l @{}}
-0.2399106  &-0.21202469 &-0.28024384 &-0.2577843  &-0.257399 &\ldots\ x_i = 300 \\ 
\end{array}] \\
\vdots\ (m=15) \\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mico :) Solves pretty well my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Just my example is an improved of your code especially for the matrix that I have not understood. I'm sorry. You can see the differences also of the packages:
`parskip`, `geometry` (for the margins) and for `\mbox` `\footnotesize` to have a little matrix. It is a solution but surely it is not the best.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos}
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{Replace the sequence of tokens per trainable column by the relative array of embeddings, using as map the output of the previous step.}

For example the column actors, which has the following structure:

['tom hanks', 'tim allen', 'don rickles', 'jim varney', 'wallace shawn', 'john ratzenberger', 'annie potts', 'john morris', 'erik von detten', 'laurie metcalf', 'r. lee ermey', 'sarah freeman', 'penn jillette', 'jack angel', 'spencer aste']

\[\Big\downarrow\]
\[\mbox{\footnotesize$
\begin{bmatrix} 
-0.30834767, &-0.26681098, &-0.2173222,  &-0.11151562, &-0.27951762 & \ldots& x_i = 300\\
-0.1721798, &-0.25406063, &-0.38693774, &-0.19798501, &-0.257399, &-0.05970115 & \ldots & x_i = 300\\
-0.2399106, &-0.21202469, &-0.28024384, &-0.2577843, &-0.257399,& \ldots &x_i = 300\\ 
\ldots (m=15) &
\end{bmatrix}$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer Sebastiano, it solves my problem. However, I accepted the answer of @Mico since (s)he added code to enable rounding of digits.

Comment: @NikSp Don't worry about it. You have chosen the best answer.